# MySQL select - get count by group

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have two tables joined and grouped, one is Orders the other one is Items.
What I want to get is the number of orders  we have in x period.

So my initial thought was to first get the count of how may times each order occurs in the dataset, then divide each line by the above number, eg, order ID 1 occurs 3 times so the count would be .33 which * 3 = 1 order.

But i am having trouble at the first step, in getting the correct count of order.id occurrences.

What I would expect to show is like this:

```
+-------+---------+------+
|order  |item     |count |
|number |         |      |
+-------+---------+------+
| 1     | ABC     |  3   |
+-------+---------+------+
| 1     | DEF     |  3   |
+-------+---------+------+
| 1     | GHI     |  3   |
+-------+---------+------+
| 2     | ABC     |  2   |
+-------+---------+------+
| 2     | DEF     |  2   |
+-------+---------+------+
| 3     | ABC     |  1   |
+-------+---------+------+
```

but I am only getting it like this:

```
+-------+---------+------+
|order  |item     |count |
|number |         |      |
+-------+---------+------+
| 1     | ABC     |  1   |
+-------+---------+------+
| 1     | DEF     |  1   |
+-------+---------+------+
| 1     | GHI     |  1   |
+-------+---------+------+
| 2     | ABC     |  1   |
+-------+---------+------+
| 2     | DEF     |  1   |
+-------+---------+------+
| 3     | ABC     |  1   |
+-------+---------+------+
```

And this is my query:

```
SELECT 
`orders`.`id` as 'order number',
`item`.`item`,
COUNT(`orders`.`id`) as ' count'
FROM `db`.`orders` 
LEFT JOIN `item` ON `item`.`order_id` = `order`.`order_id`    
GROUP BY `orders`.`id`, `item`.`item`
;
```

How?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be-

```
SELECT 
`item`.`item`,
COUNT(`orders`.`id`) as 'count'
FROM `db`.`orders` 
JOIN `item` ON `item`.`order_id` = `order`.`order_id`    
GROUP BY `item`.`item`;
```

I don't think you need same item row multiple times as you are trying to get item wise count.

Update: You can get your desired results by this one

```
SELECT t1.order_id, t2.item, t1.cnt FROM 
(
SELECT o.order_id,COUNT(i.items) cnt FROM 
item i 
JOIN orders o ON o.order_id=i.order_id
group by o.order_id
) t1 
JOIN 
item t2 ON t1.order_id=t2.order_id;
```

Comment: I can't say if this is best option but you can get your desired results by updated query.

Comment: You have more query than you need here

Comment: I wasnt able to get your code to work. Is my desired result so complicated?

Answer (score 0):

You should try following,

```
Select 
    `order`.`order_id`,
    `item`.`item`,
    `order`.`count`
from 
(
    SELECT 
        `orders`.`id` as order_id,
        COUNT(*) as 'count'
    FROM `db`.`orders` 
    group by `orders`.`id`
) as order
 JOIN `item` ON `item`.`order_id` = `order`.`order_id`
```

Comment: Worked for the first 5 records, then it just doesn't work see pic from actual output. http://i.stack.imgur.com/TClfV.jpg

Comment: Because order number is different that is why.

Comment: Let me be clearer, orders 100000051 and 100000052 both occur two times, your query returns 2 for ...51 but ....52 has 1 in first record and 2 in second record. Why? I want 2 everywhere the same order# occurs twice.

Comment: Ohhh!! I got the point, actually I understand in different aspects, let me update my query.

Comment: Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Can you please check again.

Answer (score 0):

After help from a friend, I ended up getting exactly what i wanted by using the following:

```
SELECT 
 orders.id as 'order number',
 items.item,
 (SELECT count(*) FROM db.items where items.id = sales.id) as 'order_count'
FROM db.orders 
GROUP BY orders.id, items.item
;
```